# mysqli_real_escape_string() conversion assistance

Tags: php

How would I go about converting the below strings to latest mysqli?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            if ($i == 0)
                $nameCriteria .= " IN ('".mysql_escape_string($searchInfo->nameTokens[$i])."'";
            else
                $nameCriteria .= ",'".mysql_escape_string($searchInfo->nameTokens[$i])."'";
        }
```

**I tried the the fix below but doesn't work.**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) { 
            if ($i == 0) 
                $nameCriteria .= " IN ('".((isset($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) && is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchInfo->nameTokens[$i]) : ((trigger_error("Does not Work!", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : ""))."'"; 
            else 
                $nameCriteria .= ",'".((isset($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) && is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchInfo->nameTokens[$i]) : ((trigger_error("Does not Work!.", E_USER_ERROR)) ? "" : ""))."'"; 
        }
```

**I also tried to use this but does not work either**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0)
            $nameCriteria .= " IN ('".mysqli__real_escape_string($searchInfo->nameTokens[$i])."'";
        else
            $nameCriteria .= ",'".mysqli__real_escape_string($searchInfo->nameTokens[$i])."'";
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I understand there are several other similar questions, but nothing that really helps guide me get this string fixed from original source project.

Comment: because you can't just stick an i in the function name and expect it to work as shown in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) there is also a change of arguments.....why is it today i keep seeing people make the same stupid mistake over and over again

Comment: Need to add the linnk to your `mysqli` instance in the arguments. Also, your final attempt there incorrectly has double-underscores for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this:

```
$nameCriteria = [];
foreach ($searchInfo->nameTokens as $token) {
    $nameCriteria[] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $token);
}
$nameCriteria = "IN('" . join("','", $nameCriteria) . "')";
```